# In Netlogo, why are the blue patches not overtaking the orange patches? why is it pulsing?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I´ve in through this in previous posts and i got a new problem. Im trying to abandoment a restoration processes. At the beginning orange and bue flow swiftly, but as soon as they interact non win and just change between them over and over. In the code, I stablished that if a patch is orange and it sees at least 3 blues it should change to blue, and i didnt stablish that if a blue patch is surrounded by orange it changes, however it happens. The idea is that at set up I have 3 color, and with some sliders (that would be in - if reforestado >= 3 [if random 100 <= SLIDER]) the patches changes and ultimetly blue (75) and a little bit of green (66) should win showing restauraton

This code can be copy and pasted and it should work, ignore the red patches that appear. Please set vertical limits to the world.

Why isnt the orange loosing agains the blue?

Thanks in advance.

````
 patches-own
[bordear
abandono
reforestado
potrerizado
temperatura
humedad
dosel
]
breed [ potreros potrero ]
breed [ bordes borde ]
breed [ bosques bosque ]

to setup
  resize-world 0 90 0 60
  clear-all

  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 30 and
    pxcor >= min-pxcor and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 35
    set temperatura 26.5
    set dosel 1
   set humedad 90.4
  ]
 ;Potrero
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 60 and
    pxcor >= 30 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 44
    set temperatura 29
    set dosel 84.3
   set humedad 79.3;
  ]
  ;Borde
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 90 and
    pxcor >= 60 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 66
   set temperatura 26.3
   set dosel 85.2
   set humedad 94 ;
  ]
  ;Bosque

 ;se establece la forma de la rana

 ; Se establecen las condiciones de las ranas, tamaño color y lugar de aparicion. La energia sera igual en todas las ranas en el set up.

   create-potreros 50

  [ set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color yellow
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 35]
    set heading random 45 + 45
    set energia 50
 ]   ;; red = not carrying food

 ;Potrero



    reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask potreros [
    if energia < 50 [descansar-potrero]
    if energia >= 50 and energia <= 80 [move-potrero]
    if energia > 80 [ if ticks mod 50 = 0 [reproducirse]]
    set heading random 270
      fd 1
 set energia energia - 2
  morir]

  ask patches [ restauracion ]
  ask patches [ deforestacion ]
  ask patches [abandonacion]
  ask patches [borderizacion]


if ticks >= 500 [stop]
tick
end

to restauracion
  if pcolor = 44 or pcolor = 25 or pcolor = 35[
     set reforestado count neighbors with [pcolor = 66 or pcolor = 75] ]
  if reforestado >= 3 [if random 100 <= 100 [
    set pcolor 75
    set temperatura 24.4 + random 3
    set humedad 91 + random 9
    set dosel 82 + random 5 ]
  ]


end


to deforestacion
  if pcolor = 44 or pcolor = 25 or pcolor = 75 or pcolor = 66 [
     set potrerizado count neighbors with [pcolor = 35] ]
  if potrerizado >= 3 [if random 100 <= 0 [
    set pcolor 35
    set temperatura 22.7 + random 5
    set humedad 84.5 + random 10
    set dosel 0 + random 10]
  ]
end
to abandonacion
  if pcolor = 35 [
     set abandono count neighbors with [pcolor = 44 or pcolor = 25] ]
  if abandono >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 25
    set temperatura 24.6 + random 8
    set humedad 68 + random 14
    set dosel 79 + random 9]
  ]

end

to borderizacion
  if pcolor = 66 [
     set bordear count neighbors with [pcolor = 44] ]
  if bordear >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set temperatura 24 + random 6
    set humedad 80 + random 20
    set dosel 80 + random 5]
]

end

to move-potrero
  ask neighbors in-radius 2
     [if temperatura >= 28.6 or temperatura <= 22.6 or dosel >= 5 or humedad <= 84
      [ set pcolor red
       ;facexy random 30 random 60
      ;fd 5
      ;set energia energia - 10]]
    ;[ask potreros [descansar-potrero]]
  ]]



end

to descansar-potrero
  ifelse pcolor = 35 [
    set energia energia + 6]
  [set energia energia + 1]

end

to reproducirse
  if energia > 80 [ if random 100 > 60 [set energia energia - 70
      hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 2
      set energia energia / 3]]]
end
  to morir
  if energia <= 1 [die]

end ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, once your patches set `abandono` to some value in `to abandonacion`, they never reset it unless their `pcolor` is returned to 35. So, you have *all* patches evaluating the `if abandono >=3...` code. For a quick fix to see what I mean, change your `to abandonacion` chunk to:

```
to abandonacion
  set abandono 0
  if pcolor = 35 [
    set abandono count neighbors with [pcolor = 44 or pcolor = 25] ]
  if abandono >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 25
    set temperatura 24.6 + random 8
    set humedad 68 + random 14
    set dosel 79 + random 9]
  ]
  
end
```

The above simply resets the `abandono` to 0 right before evaluating the `abandano` count to ensure that all patches are starting "fresh." There are other ways to address this, but how you actually go about it may depend on if you are tracking the number of `abandono` patches every tick.

Comment: Hi @Luke C thanks! For the answer. I think that i should make every patch to 0. I'm planning on doing a graph showing the change in proportion and I don't know but i don't see how this fix could generate a proble on counting. Ill keep you posted!